# Nuxt 2 asyncData not persisting data on page refresh in production mode, how to solve this issue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, lifecycle, asyncdata

My `asyncData` does not work correctly in Nuxt 2?

```
async asyncData ({ store, query }) {
    const type = query.type || "All";
    const search = query.search || "";

    await store.dispatch("demos/fetchData", {
        type,
        search
    });

    return { type, search };
},
```

It works very well on Development mode, but Production, it does not work.

When I refresh page at URL: localhost:3000/MyPage?type=Spa. This page redirect to: localhost:3000/MyPage/?type=Spa and now the data is data of "All" page not Spa page.

I do not reassign type and search after asyncData

I expect when i refresh the page this data still there.